# Using multiple ids with WC_Order - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-rest-api

im trying to find a way to use multiple ids with WC_Order. it works fine when using a single id however multiple don't work.

```
$order_id = array("156","155","156"); // The order_id

// get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id )

// The loop to get the order items which are WC_Order_Item_Product objects since WC 3+
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ){
    //Get the product ID
    $item_product->get_product_id();
    //Get the WC_Product object
    $item_product->get_product();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to loop in each id.

```
$order_ids = array("156","155","156"); // The order_id


foreach( $order_ids as $order_id ){
    // get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // The loop to get the order items which are WC_Order_Item_Product objects since WC 3+
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ){
        //Get the product ID
        $item_product->get_product_id();
        //Get the WC_Product object
        $item_product->get_product();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Great thank you :) i had a feeling i missed something

Comment: what's not working with variables? if you need variation id, you can do something like: `$variation_id = $item_product->get_variation_id();`

Comment: Its works for single products however when i try with a variable product it doesn't match the right price with the correct product variation id.

Comment: `$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
  
$variation_product_id = $product_variations [0]['variation_id'];
           
 $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_product_id );
            
$t_dy =  $variation_product->get_price();
            
$item_qty = $item_obj['qty'];
            
$it_total = $item_qty * $t_dy;
            
$td = wc_update_order_item_meta($item_id, '_line_total', $it_total);`

Comment: would be better if you create another post question for that.. the comment is too limited to answer

Comment: Okay thanks will do - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856207/getting-the-correct-variation-price-with-wc-order-woocommerce